# 'StringVar' obj is not callable

Tags: string, class, object, variables, tkinter

it said the stringvar obj is not callable? i dont know how to fix this can someone help me. thanks

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
```

i use self.Username etc with a first letter capslock so i can pass it on database connection but it said that stringvar is not callable.

```
class register:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.Username = StringVar()
        self.Password = StringVar()
        self.Confirm_Password = StringVar()
        self.Fullname = StringVar()
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('500x200')
        window.resizable(0, 0)
        window.configure(bg="deep sky blue")
        window.title("Register")

        l1 = Label(self.window, text="Username:", font=("Arial", 15), bg="deep sky blue")
        l1.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.fullname = Entry(self.window, width=30, bd=5, textvariable=self.Fullname)
        self.fullname.place(x=200, y=10)

        l1 = Label(self.window, text="Username:", font=("Arial", 15), bg="deep sky blue")
        l1.place(x=10, y=60)

        self.username = Entry(self.window, width=30, bd=5, textvariable=self.Username)
        self.username.place(x=200, y=60)

        l2 = Label(self.window, text="Password:", font=("Arial", 15), bg="deep sky blue")
        l2.place(x=10, y=110)

        self.password = Entry(self.window, width=30, show="*", bd=5, textvariable=self.Password)
        self.password.place(x=200, y=110)

        l3 = Label(self.window, text="Confirm Password:", font=("Arial", 15), bg="deep sky blue")
        l3.place(x=10, y=170)

        self.confirm_password = Entry(self.window, width=30, show="*", bd=5, textvariable=self.Confirm_Password)
        self.confirm_password.place(x=200, y=170)

        b1 = Button(self.window, text="Sign in", font=("Arial", 15), bg="#ffc22a", command=self.submit)
        b1.place(x=170, y=150)

        b2 = Button(self.window, text="Back", font=("Arial", 15), bg="#ffc22a", command=self.submit)
        b2.place(x=250, y=150)
```

heres how i pass it did i make mistake on passing the variable?

```
    connection = sqlite3.connect('RegLog.db')
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RegLog( username TEXT, Password TEXT, "
                "ConfirmPassword TEXT)")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

    def submit(self):
        check_counter = 0
        warn = ""
        if self.fullname.get() == "":
            warn = "Full Name can't be empty"
        else:
            check_counter += 1
        if self.username.get() == "":
            warn = "Full Name can't be empty"
        else:
            check_counter += 1

        if self.password.get() == "":
            warn = "Email Field can't be empty"
        else:
            check_counter += 1
        if self.confirm_password.get() == "":
            warn = "Sorry, can't sign up make sure all fields are complete"
        else:
            check_counter += 1
        if self.password.get() != self.confirm_password.get():
            warn = "Passwords didn't match!"
        if check_counter == 4:
            try:
                connection = sqlite3.connect("RegLog.db")
                cur = connection.cursor()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO RegLog values(?,?,?)",
                            (self.Username.get(), self.Password.get(), self.Confirm_Password.get(), self.Fullname()))

                connection.commit()
                connection.close()
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "New account created successfully")
```

and also i think this exception is thrown whenever run the program.it said expected type 'str|None',got 'Exception' instead

```
            except Exception as ep:
                messagebox.showerror('Error1', ep)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', warn)


def page():
    window = Tk()
    register(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to post the full error traceback.

Comment: wdym full error traceback like the image?

Comment: `self.Fullname()` should be `self.Fullname.get()` because `self.Fullname` is a tkinter `StingVar`.

Comment: on the def __init__ part?

Comment: It is simple to find the line by using the search feature of your editor.